# Examples of homomorphisms outside algebra and topology?

Tags: category-theory, group-homomorphism

I recently started looking at category theory and I see that homomorphisms are a pretty important concept. So far I have seen two "flavours" of homomorphisms in mathematics:

1. homomorphisms between algebraic structures (groups, rings, fields, vector  spaces, etc.) which preserve the algebraic operations, whatever they may be
2. continuous functions between topological spaces

I get the sense that there are probably more examples, but I just can't think of any. Moreover it seems odd to me that there are so many examples of homomorphisms in algebra, and yet we have continuous functions from topology just sitting alone all by itself.

Could anyone point out other examples of homomorphisms?

I am primarily looking for examples that have to do with so-called "concrete categories" which non-category theorists would be familiar with prior to studying category theory. I'm aware that functors are a sort of homomorphism between categories, but I'm hoping to find more concrete examples than that.

Comment: An easy example: monotone functions between posets are the "homomorphisms" in the category of all posets.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for but have you heard of homomorphic encryption?

Comment: @ZeroXLR Thanks!

Comment: @AlanWolfe I haven't heard of that. Looking briefly at wikipedia, it appears to be what I would call an "algebra-style" homomorphism, but it is a very intriguing practical application nonetheless. Thank-you!

Comment: A more "exotic" example. In the category of proofs, the objects are logical formulae and the "homomorphisms" are logical deductions between formulae!

Comment: @ZeroXLR Interseting. Mathematical logic and proof theory are areas I am not very experienced in, so I will have to look into those.

Comment: You can find plenty of examples like these in Awodey's Category Theory which will also teach you the subject from a pretty elementary level. The author provides the textbook for free I think. Check google...

Comment: We can connect the two types of morphisms you describe by consider continuous linear operators between topological vector spaces (like Banach or Hilbert spaces). Now the continuous functions from topology don't sit alone by themselves any more ;-)

Comment: Back in your school days and geometry lessons, did you notice that all problems that asked for constructing triangles were really about isomorphism classes of triangles?

Comment: Well, if the $\lim$ is taken as a (partial) opration (of infinite arity), we can regard continuous functions as (partial, infinitary) algebra morphisms. Moreover, topological spaces with continuous functions make just the category of algebras for the *ultrafilter monad*.

Comment: Differentiable, smooth, analytic, measurable, convex, piecewise linear, regular and rational (in algebraic geometry,) are some other kinds of functions which live in categories more similar to Top than to Grp.